# Count How Many time a value appear inside a collection in a dictonary

Tags: c#

i have the following code:

```
    private Dictionary<string, user> totalUsers = new Dictionary<string, user>();
```

user type have some values, 1 of them is List,

for example

```
            totalUsers[User].totalUsers.Add(killedPlayers);
            totalUsers[User].totalUsers.Add("Test");
            totalUsers[User].totalUsers.Add(killedPlayers);
            totalUsers[User].totalUsers.Add(killedPlayers);
```

what i want to do is to count how many times "visitPlayer" value is writen inside,

i can do that with a code like that,

```
            foreach (string name in totalUsers[User].killedPlayers)
            {
                if (name == dyingPlayer)
                { count += 1; }
            }
```

but is there a way to do it without going with the foreach loop?

thanks.

Answer (score 4):

`totalUsers[User].killedPlayers.Count(name => name == dyingPlayer)`

Comment: syntax is different, but its basically the same

Comment: Where does the overload of `Count` that takes a predicate exist?

Answer (score 2):

```
var groups = YourData.GroupBy(item => item.name).Select(n => new
        {
            name= n.Key,
            count = n.Count()
        };
```